# How should I support offline mode using DynamoDB and iOS?

Tags: ios, amazon-dynamodb, realm

This is a little bit of Parse fallout.

I'm moving an app to use DynamoDB but it doesn't seem to support any kind of offline mode.

How should I do this?

I'd like to use Realm but I'll end up having to manage synchronising and object <-> noSQL. Should I use a flag on a row to indicate it has been synced?

Should I try and keep the row flat like it is in Dynamo?

I don't think the sync part of Cognito is applicable here.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used DynamoDB before, but I just read through the iOS documentation on Amazon's website, and I THINK integrating the two should be possible, and relatively easy.

It looks like you define data models in DynamoDB the same way as Realm: create a subclass of `AWSDynamoDBObjectModel` and add your properties. As this is the case, as long as you created a Realm `Object` (or `RLMObject` in Objective-C) that had the same matching properties, you should (theoretically) be able to simply pass DynamoDB objects directly to Realm to be saved:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
    realm.create(MyRealmSubclass.self, value: MyDynamoDBObject, update: true)
}
```

Realm is very smart in being able to use KVC to see if any objects passed to it conform to the schema of its model objects and to automatically retrieve and save that information.

(NB: In order for `update:` to work properly, you'll also need to ensure your objects share a common primary key property as well).

From the sounds of it, if you're looking to then modify the locally saved data in Realm while the app is offline, and then push that modified data the device is back online, then it'll be up to you to convert the Realm model objects back into DynamoDB objects in order to be pushed back up to AWS.

You could certainly add additional properties to the Realm model, such as a boolean `hasChanges` flag, or a `lastModifiedDate` date object in order to be able to check that an offline object has changes that need uploading.

Let me know if you need any additional clarification!

*(Full disclosure: I work for Realm.)*

Comment: What a great idea! I'll give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: The equivalent API method in Objective-C would be `[RLMObject createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:]`! :)

Comment: I'm not sure it would work exactly the same way since I don't think Android has an equivalent concept of key-value coding as iOS (Stop me if I'm wrong! ;) ). If worse comes to worse, you could simply have two sets of objects: a DynamoDB model object and a Realm model object and simply copy the values between the two.

Comment: @TiM dude!  I have a similar question: consider the case of the server side being an ordinary SQL database - in fact, AmazonRDS. The data is a bit relational. Now, there are products like Zumero that completely sync-up MSFT SQLServer, and your iphone/android; but that's no good since this is an ordinary SQL database, RDS, not MSFT's SQLServer.  I THINK I can use realm on my iphone/android to do this - what do you think? Relatedly, can you point me to the ideal forum to discuss this (perhaps pm me if you prefer). Cheers!

Comment: @TiM How to extend model from both classes "AWSDynamoDBObjectModel" and "RLMObject" `class User: Object, Codable, AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {  }` I want to achive something like this.

Comment: You can't subclass one class from two separate classes in this way. You'll need to create two separate subclasses and then copy the values between them as needed. It might make sense to define a common protocol that both classes adopt in order to ensure they have the exact same properties.